# Pandas: Why does accessing an element by integer index return a different object to named index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

When accessing an element in a Pandas Series by number index or named index, the same value is returned. However, when using the 'is' comparison operator on the two returned values, False is returned.

```
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series([100, 200, 300, 400], ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta'])

print(ser[0] == ser['alpha'])
print(ser[0] is ser['alpha'])
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Can someone explain why the two methods return different objects? Is the result a copy of the value, rather than the actual object in the Series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because pandas returns a copy (new object) every time:

```
In [23]: id(ser['alpha'])
Out[23]: 146103488

In [24]: id(ser['alpha'])
Out[24]: 146103536

In [25]: id(ser['alpha'])
Out[25]: 146103560

In [26]: id(ser[0])
Out[26]: 146103584

In [27]: id(ser[0])
Out[27]: 146103512

In [28]: id(ser[0])
Out[28]: 146103608
```